# Genons in Bilayer Quantum Hall systems

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, research-level, quantum-hall-effect

For experts on Quantum Hall systems, I have a question regarding what are called "genons" in the quantum hall literature.
These were introduced fairly recently and are discussed frequently in the context of bilayer quantum hall systems wherein you can connect the two layers by "wormholes" such that the resulting theory lives on some higher genus Riemann surface.

I've seen a picture in multiple places e.g., in Fig. 2b of

[arxiv:1112.3311](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3311)

where they show this bilayer system connected by a branch cut and then flip the top layer over to get a wormhole between the two. What I'm wondering is if in doing this process, the braiding of the genons changes? Suppose I take 3 pairs of such branch cuts. Now I can think about getting some braiding for these genons. Would these change upon flipping over the top layer? It seems to me that they will but I've never seen a discussion of how this flipping effects the braiding of the genons.